# Formatting a timer to mm:ss from seconds

Tags: c#, format, tostring, timespan

I'm somewhat new to programming, but I have some knowledge in coding. I've been stuck for a few hours now trying different ways of doing this, seems straight-forward but I'm not getting a positive result. I would like a simple mm:ss format from a counter counting seconds. I've tried this:

```
if(instruct.activeSelf == false)
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    string fmt = @"mm\:ss";
    timerText.text = "Time: " + timer.ToString(fmt);
}
```

And this:

```
if(instruct.activeSelf == false)
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timer);
    timerText.text = "Time: " + ts.ToString();
}
```

This code is under the update class, after instructions I want the timer to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the format string with a `TimeSpan`value, it works:

```
if(instruct.activeSelf == false) {
  timer += Time.deltaTime;
  TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timer);
  timerText.text = "Time: " + ts.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
}
```

Comment: I get error CS1501: no overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments

Comment: use ts.Ticks.ToString(@"mm\:ss");

Comment: @Kyle: Naturally I tested the code, but that overload is only supported from framework 4.0. If you are using an older framework then you would create a `DateTime` value instead: `DateTime ts = DateTime.Today.AddSeconds(timer);`. You can use the same code for formatting it.

Comment: Success!!! Thank you Guffa!! That was exactly the problem, I didn't doubt your code working, I was just confused as to why mine wouldn't.